# how to Use the same screen navigation animation both on Android/iOS with React Native navigation v6

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

**How to Use the same screen navigation animation both on Android/iOS with React Native + React Navigation v6 ?**

Answer (score 1):

Use [animation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator#animation) prop in `screenOptions` to define default and `options` per screen. Note that not all options are supported in both Android and iOS.

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{headerShown: false, animation: 'slide_from_right'}}>
  <Stack.Screen
    options={{animation: 'fade'}}
...
  />
...
</Stack.Navigator>
```